# Horizontal scrolling of tableview with swipe gesture left and right

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement the `uitableview` with horizontal scroll. I was taken scrollview and added tableview on scrollview. I set the content size of the scrollview is greater than frame size. So that it can scroll horizontally. But when I added swipe gesture on uitableview it is not performing the actions.

code snippet is here

```
leftswipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
    leftswipe.delegate = self;
    leftswipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

    rightswipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
    rightswipe.delegate = self;
    rightswipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
        if ( sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )
        {
            NSLog(@" *** SWIPE LEFT ***");
            index1++;
            self.tableHeaderLabel.text = [self.categoriesLabelArray objectAtIndex:index1];
            [self.feedsTableView reloadData];

        }
        if ( sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ){
            NSLog(@" *** SWIPE RIGHT ***");
            index1--;
            self.tableHeaderLabel.text = [self.categoriesLabelArray objectAtIndex:index1];
            [self.feedsTableView reloadData];


        }
}
```

I want to reload table when it swiped left or right.
But for now it is not working.

Comment: You want an horizontal scrollview AND an horizontal swipe gesture management ? It's normal that you have conflict... You should consider using a two finger for your gesture

Comment: Horizontal scrollview is implemented successfully but swipe gesture not implemented

Comment: Have you added leftswipe and rightswipe to any view?

Comment: What does this have to do with `xcode`?

Comment: Use just one swipe gesture recogniser and do: swipeGR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

Comment: You don't need a swipe gesture. When the tableViews frame is big enough and you set the scrollViews contentSize equal to the tableViews bounds, the scrollView will give you scroll capability by default. If you want scroll event management, use the scrollViewDelegate protocol

Comment: You may achieve this behaviour with a UICollectionView. But its only available in iOS 6 and above

Comment: ok I am trying to use only srollview delegate but how can I get the direction of scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add tableView in a scrollView , your gestureRecognizer maybe covered by scrollView's gestureRecognizer.

you can try implement you code in

```
CGFloat lastOffset_x = 0;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     CGFloat currentOffSet_x = scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
     if(lastOffset_x > currentOffSet_x){
         //direction left
     }else{
         //direction right
     }
     lastOffset_x = scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
}
```

and track scroll direction yourself.

ps:remember to adjust scrollView's contentSize as `tableView.frame.size.width*numberOfYourTableView`.

Comment: hello, i edited my answer, please have try, and let me know if it worked or not.:)

Comment: I tried you code. But after bouncing of tableview to top currentOffSet_x becomes zero. And app gets crash. So can you please edit the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add that UITableView delegate method  :

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

By the way, you can instantiate only one UIGestureRecognizer, by setting the `direction` property like that :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRecognizer:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when I need to display a horizontal table view, I just use:

```
-(void)setupProductsTableView {
        self.innerProductsTable.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        self.innerProductsTable.delegate = self;
        self.innerProductsTable.dataSource = self;
    }
```

If I need to track scrolling I use:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        int lastVisibleCell = [[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject ] row];
        //do some with last displayed cell
    }
```

Regards,
Venelin

Answer (score 0):

write only the following codes in SwipeRecognizer.

```
- (void) SwipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if ( sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )
    {
        NSLog(@" *** SWIPE LEFT ***");
        index1++;

        [self.feedsTableView reloadData];

    }
    if ( sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ){
        NSLog(@" *** SWIPE RIGHT ***");
        index1--;

        [self.feedsTableView reloadData];


    }
}
```

and write tableview delegate method (for Data) as the following:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.categoriesLabelArray objectAtIndex:index1];


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(index1 == 0)
        //set tableCellDataArray
    if(index1 == 1)
        //set tableCellDataArray
    if(index1 == 2)
        //set tableCellDataArray
    //...
    //...
    if(index1 == n)
        //set tableCellDataArray
}
```

and yes don't forget to add the following to viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     leftswipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
     leftswipe.delegate = self;
     leftswipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

     rightswipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeRecognizer:)];
     rightswipe.delegate = self;
     rightswipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

     [self.feedsTableView addGestureRecognizer: leftswipe];
     [self.feedsTableView addGestureRecognizer: rightswipe];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is showing content in tableview (only 1 row and when you scroll horizontally) the best way will be transforming the tableview. this will fix all the thing you doesn't need to take scrollview also.

if the requirement is other case ... Please explain your requirement bit meow detailed. So we can have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UICollectionView`!

Change the `scrollDirection` property of your flow layout to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.

```
[yourFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
```